# Work with very large vectors in R

Tags: r, vector, large-data

I have to subtract each entry value of one vector by every value of another vector. Each vector has 1e6 size.

If I just do

```
library(doParallel)
library(foreach)
cl<-makeCluster(12)
registerDoParallel(cl)

mV1 <- rnorm(1e6)
mV2 <- rnorm(1e6)
mResult <- foreach(i=1:1e6,.combine=rbind) %dopar% {
  mResult <- mV1[i] - mV2
  mResult
}
plot(ecdf(mResult))
```

I get an error because R cannot allocate a file larger than 1.6 GB. My computer has 16GB of memmory and I'm working in Win7 x64, RStudio Version 0.98.1028 64-bits and R x64 3.1.1. Is there a way to do this in this system? Can I reduce the `object size` in R?

Thanks

Comment: do you use 64-bit R?

Comment: Yes, RStudio Version 0.98.1028 64-bits and R x64 3.1.1

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to create an object containing 1e12 elements, which will be way too large to fit into 16GB (try `x = 1:1e12`). Maybe some of the packages like `bigmemory` will help you, but I've never used them. If it's possible to calculate an ecdf for a dataset using small chunks at a time then that's another option.

Comment: Thanks, I've checked that package and it says `If
x
is a
big.matrix
, then
x[1:5,]
is returned as an R
matrix
containing the first five rows of
x
.` So I don't know if it may really help.

Comment: Also `package ‘bigmemory’ is not available (for R version 3.1.1)`

Comment: If your aim is the ecdf you don't need 1e12 values. A sample of that (e.g., `mV1 - mV2`) would be sufficient.

Comment: In my case I do, because in those 1e12 values I have 1e3 that are < zero and the rest is > zero. So if I sample say 1e6 or even 1e9 I won't catch them.